# I can't inherit shared properties from a base class in a child class, can I?

Tags: vb.net

This is another one of my "I think it's not possible but I need confirmation" questions.

I have a base class for a bunch of child classes.  Right now, this base class has a few common properties the children use, like `Name`.  The base is an abstract class (MustInherit). Technically, this means that everytime a child class is instantiated, it lugs around, in memory, its own copy of `Name`.  The thing is, `Name` is going to be a fixed value for all instances of a given child.  I.e., `Child1.Name` will return `"child_object1"`, and `Child2.Name` will return `"child_object2"`.

This property seems a perfect candidate for a shared property, but then the problem arises.  It seems that if I define `Name` as a shared property in the base class, regardless of what children classes derive from base, all will share the same `Name`, which is the exact purpose of shared properties (or methods, etc).

The only workaround that I can think of for this is to remove `Name` from the base class and re-implement it as a shared property directly in each child class.  This seems to defeat the function of having a base class in the first place, though.  At least in principle.

So my question is what is the preferred approach to tackling this problem from a design standpoint?  Assume at least 50 derived child classes from a single, abstract base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume when you say "child object" you mean "child class."  Don't mix up the terminology; it makes your question more confusing.

That said, I have used this pattern myself many times.  You are right to think of shared/static, but you can't apply it here since each instance of a class derived from the base class can have a different name.  I see nothing at all wrong with having an abstract property that is overridden to return a constant value.

Think about it -- the purpose of an abstract member is to allow child classes to provide their own implementation of it.  When you ask an object "what is your name?" *something* needs to know.  The child class itself is the perfect place for such data, and implementing an abstract member makes perfect sense.

If the Name property will be returning something based on the name of the type itself, you can obtain that with `GetType().Name`, and therefore might be able to consolidate some of the name code into a default, virtual implementation of the property, and override it when the default implementation doesn't do the right thing.  This could eliminate a lot of boilerplate code for a negligible performance penalty.

(To answer the question posed in your question title, yes, technically all non-private shared/static members of a type are inherited by all subtypes.  But you cannot override them, because that makes no sense for shared/static members.)

Comment: @cdhowie: I edited it a little.  I figured they were semi-interchangeable terms.

Comment: @cdhowie: I've thought about an abstract approach.  But I can't mix that with shared (at least in VB.Net).  I do have the names for my derived classes stored as Consts in a module, so I could define an abstract property in the base class, override in the child class and return the constant.  The initial approach was to reduce the clutter in each class, though, by keeping the common property defined in the base class, and having each derived/child class do a `MyBase.Name = CHILD1_NAME` in its parameterless constructor.

Comment: @Kumba: But `Shared` means that there is *only once instance* of the property, and it belongs to the base type.  So setting the property in the parameterless constructor of each class means that **the name of each object will be the name of the most recently-created object.**  You are right; you can't mix abstract with shared.  So remove the shared modifier and keep abstract.  Think of "shared" as creating a global variable -- and that doesn't make any sense in this context, does it?

Comment: @cdhowie: Sorry, I should have clarified, but when I stated I was using the `MyBase.Name = ...` approach, those implementations _were not shared_, so this wasn't causing an issue.  I was stating that I chose that approach over defining ReadOnly properties that return a constant in each derived class to reduce code clutter.  If I have 50+ derived objects, each containing a simple ReadOnly Name property, then I figured that's a lot of extra code being generated *versus* a call in the constructor to the base class copy of Name.  Of course, I am probably overanalyzing things.  Bad habit of mine.

Comment: To continue, I am now at the phase of re-evaluating earlier design decisions and so seeking comment on whether I chose a semi-decent way, or if I should re-engineer things a bit.  Name is just the best example to go with...I have a few other properties in the Base class that are much the same.

Comment: @cdhowie: Did some benchmarking, and the performance difference is negligible between using the abstract/overridden property versus just implementing it in the base class (not as a shared) and setting a value form the derived class in the constructor.  Thanks for the advice, though!

Comment: @Kumba: Yeah, using an abstract (what is effectively virtual) property will incur a small performance penalty for the vtable lookup.  But you should go with whatever design makes sense for your purposes.  A non-virtual property with a public getter and a protected setter isn't a bad way to go.